# Assigning one class to 2 variables and comparing them

Tags: java

Sorry if this has been asked before but I wanted to know:

Say i make a new instance of a class and assign it to a variable e.g.:  `MyClassName myclass = new MyClassName(some parameters);`  and I assign this to another variable or put it in a List e.g.:  `list.add(myclass);`. If I compare the two in an if clause  `if (list.get(0).equals(myclass)` would it return true?

Forgive me if the question might be a bit vague or unclear.

Comment: Have you tried it? Have you implemented `.equals`?

Comment: What happens when you try?  Have you ever encountered a scenario where two references to the same object are *not* considered "equal"?  Do you have an example of code which is behaving in an unexpected way?

Comment: @hev1 The OP is specifically asking about _the same object_.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- I know, but the answer depends on whether or not equals was implemented correctly (or if it was not implemented).

Comment: By definition, an object is equal to itself using .equals, but also using '=='.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways of matching object in java:

1. matching one object's with another object like: obj1 == obj2
2. another one is obj1.equals(obj2)....in this case obj1 must have a methods called equals...

Now, what happens in the second case: `equals` method is custom design in most cases, i.e. you've to provide it. And in some cases (for builtin classes), it's provided by java, for example for `String`. So, I hope you understood that `obj1 == obj2` does not call on the `equals` method. That is because java does not have any fancy thing like *operator overriding* as in C++. So, the `equals` method is generally used to check if two objects content are same or not.

So, what happens when you do `obj1 == obj2`? It just checks if `obj1`'s object reference is the same or not as `obj2`. That means they both target the same memory or not. So, it is possible that, `obj1 == obj2` may return false even if there contents are same.

Let me show you an example:

```
class SomeClass {
  private int x;
  public SomeClass(int x) {
    this.x = x;
  }
  public boolean equals(SomeClass o) {
    return this.x == o.x;
  }
}
```

Now, write some tests:

```
SomeClass a = new SomeClass(12);
SomeClass b = new SomeClass(12);
SomeClass c = a;

System.out.println(a == c); // print true
System.out.println(a == b); // print false

System.out.println(a.equals(c)); // print true
System.out.println(a.equals(b)); // print true
```

Hope this clears everything. If anything is unclear ask me in the comment.